# Define default implementation for injection in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, qualifiers

I have a base class that is extended by some other classes. Therefore I have to provide qualifiers for being able to inject a specific instance.

I wonder if I could mark any of these classes (eg the most upper class) as default class, which would be picked up if no qualifier is provided on `@Autowired`?

```
@Service
//@Qualifier("Parent")
class ParentRunner;

@Service
@Qualifier("Child")
class ChildRunner extends ParentRunner;
```

The following does at least not work:

```
@Autowired
//@Qualifier("Parent")
private ParentRunner runner;
```

Comment: You can mark one implementation with `@Primary` which will then be used as default. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: Great that works! Would you mind adding this as an answer, not as comment, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can mark one implementation with `@Primary` which will then be used as default. When using xml you can use the `primary` element inside the `bean` element to set an instance to the primary bean instance to use.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: The problem with javax Primary is that this will not be a default that can be overriden. (Except through xml config) So from my point of view its not a default but the only implementation active ones this class is in the classpath. There is a jira entry which requests using priority reather than primary to allow declaring a higher precedence than the default implementation: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10548

Comment: `@Primary` only kicks in if there are multiple candidates for resolving. If you specify a specific `@Qualifier` it should match only a single candidate and then that one should be used.